# Installing Sevntu in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, checkstyle, sevntu-checkstyle

I am wondering how I can install Sevntu on Android Studio without using the JAR. I've added the maven url and everything works when I point to the local JAR file during the third-party configuration for Checkstyle, but is there a way to not use the JAR?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. At the time of this writing (early 2019), you must use the JAR.
The Checkstyle plugin does not currently support build tool integration, and that is a feature that is also not on the roadmap at the moment ([#107](https://github.com/jshiell/checkstyle-idea/issues/107)).

Comment: Does this mean it won't work in tools like CircleCI?

Comment: No, what I described is a limitation of Android Studio (actually, of the Checkstyle plugin for Android Studio). CI services would execute your build tool, so you're good.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using maven, just include the sevntu maven plugin as a dependency with checkstyle.

Example: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/c0e131dbc43a17537498432b14cc7e7743ecf407/pom.xml#L547-L551

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.sevntu-checkstyle</groupId>
    <artifactId>sevntu-checkstyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.32.0</version>
</dependency>
```